# Why doesn't my ListBox show me the text of the Item I added?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a ListBox in WPF where I'm adding items through an OpenFileDialog. Here the Code where I add the Items to my ListBox. **(tbxFiles = my listbox name)**

```cs
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames)
    {
        path.Add(filename);

        for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
        {
            tbxFiles.Items.Add(path[i]);
        }
    }
    var _items = this.tbxFiles.Items.Cast<string>().Distinct().ToArray();

    this.tbxFiles.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var item in _items)
    {
        this.tbxFiles.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

When I look at the breakpoint I can see that the content of what I added to my ListBox is correct. The problem starts showing as I added this DataTemplate to my ListBox:

```xml
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="15,20,31,15" MinHeight="25" Name="tbxFiles" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ListText" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <RadioButton Grid.Column="1"  Content="TF"  />
                            <RadioButton Grid.Column="2"  Content="AF" />
                            <ComboBox Grid.Column="3"  Text="Periode"  />
                            <Button Grid.Column="4"  Click="RemoveMark_Click"  Content="Delete" />
                         </Grid>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                 </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

The moment I added this DataTemplate it stopped showing me the text, even when I remove the Items from the DataTemplate it isn't showing anything. Maybe I should start showing the text in the **textbox** I created, but I cannot adress it's name because it is in a DataTemplate. Have any of you an idea of how I can show the name I want to have in the ListBox?

Comment: Try <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0"/> in the template

Comment: thats working thx

Comment: @T.Schwarz why people just comment and not posting an answer?

Comment: @Erez Because one-line-answers (even if they're fully correct) tend to be downvoted.

Comment: @PMF - Thanks, I didnt' know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use binding for your ListBox,
change XAML source to:

```xml
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="15,20,31,15" MinHeight="25" Name="tbxFiles"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock x:Name="ListText" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
                                    <RadioButton Grid.Column="1"  Content="TF"  />
                                    <RadioButton Grid.Column="2"  Content="AF" />
                                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="3"  Text="Periode"  />
                                    <Button Grid.Column="4"  Click="RemoveMark_Click"  Content="Delete" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
```

and add two View model classes:

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
   public List<FileItem> Items { get; set; }
}
public class FileItem
{
   public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

and you may bind loading file names to your ListBox like this:

```cs
            var vm = new ViewModel();
            vm.Items = new List<FileItem>();
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames) 
                {
                    vm.Items.Add(new FileItem { FileName = filename });
                }

                tbxFiles.DataContext = vm;
            }
```

---

In a proper MVVM approach you would however have a view model like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<FileItem> Items { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();
}
```

with a readonly ObservableCollection property, which is once assigned to the DataContext of the Window, e.g. like

```
private readonly ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

and used like this:

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    viewModel.Items.Clear();

    foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames) 
    {
        viewModel.Items.Add(new FileItem { FileName = filename });
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of reassigning the DataContext it would make more sense to create the view model once, and only update the Items property. You would typically have a readonly ObsevableCollection property that is cleared and re-populated each time ShowDialog is called.

Comment: Also `vm.Items.Add(filename);` and `vm.Items.Add(path[i]);` are pointless in the context of this example. There should be a single `vm.Items.Add(new FileItem { FileName = filename });`

Comment: Also consider editing the DataContext part. `tbxFiles.DataContext = vm;` is in no way better than `tbxFiles.ItemsSource = vm.Items;`. IMO it is even worse, and hence a bad advice.

Comment: Becouse in XAML has ```ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"``` for this reason i simply past it

Comment: If you look at how the Items collection is populated in the edited answer, you will realize that the code does no longer directly access any view elements, and could hence be moved into the view model entirely.